# Specify non-custom type converter for QVariant

Tags: qt, qt5

I use QObject property serialization like this:

```
QMetaProperty metaProperty = obj->metaObject()->property(i);
QString attrName = metaProperty.name();
QVariant attrValue = metaProperty.read(obj);
serializedJson.insert("name", attrName);
serializedJson.insert("value", attrValue.toString());
```

But QVariant::toString() method has some incorrect behaviour when working with `float` properties: code

```
float f = 0.0001;
qDebug() << QVariant(f).toString();
qDebug() << QVariant(f).value<QString>();
```

prints:

```
"9.999999747378752e-05"
"9.999999747378752e-05"
```

Ok, I know, there is pretty QString::number() method,

```
float f = 0.0001;
qDebug() << QString::number(f);
```

which gives me:

```
"0.0001"
```

But I don't want to complicate the code:

```
QMetaProperty metaProperty = obj->metaObject()->property(i);
QString attrName = metaProperty.name();
QVariant attrValue = metaProperty.read(obj);

QString stringified = "";

// special handling of float properties !
if (attrValue.type() == static_cast<QVariant::Type>(QMetaType::Float))
    stringified = QString::number(attrValue.toFloat());
else
    stringified = attrValue.value<QString>();

serializedJson.insert("name", attrName);
serializedJson.insert("value", stringified );
```

Then I tried to register own converter:

```
QMetaType::registerConverter<float, QString>(Converters::floatToString);
```

Unfortunately, Qt gives me an error:

```
Error : static assertion failed: QMetaType::registerConverter: At least one of the types must be a custom type.
```

How can I define custom type-conversion for human-readable type serialization?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to register `float` and `QString` types that are already registered hence the error:

> static assertion failed: `QMetaType::registerConverter`: At least one of the types must be a custom type.

See the list of supported types in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum).

One solution could be to extend `QString` to create a custom type.

Here's an example:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QMetaType>

struct FQString final : QString
{
    using QString::operator=;

    static QString convert( const float f )
    {
        return QString::number( f );
    }
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( FQString );

int main()
{
    QMetaType::registerConverter<float, FQString>( FQString::convert );

    const float f = 0.0001;
    const QVariant v( f );

    const QString s = v.value<FQString>();
    qDebug() << "Value:" << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value: "0.0001"
```

With this solution, you could write something like this for your code:

```
QString stringified = attrValue.value<FQString>();
```